# How to avoid blank spaces while loading data from Teradata to Databricks

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, teradata, databricks

I encountered with a blank space issue after setting the Teradata JDBC Driver connection parameter to CHARSET = 'UTF8'.

Teradata JDBC URL : jdbc:teradata://server-name:server-port/database-server-name,TMODE = ANSI,CHARSET = 'UTF8',COLUMN_NAME = ON

For Instance : If table has column value as 'FIRST' then usually it's length is 5 but it is doubling the character space now the length is 10 'FIRST     '

Can someone provide me the alternative instead of using trim in PySpark.

Comment: There are challenges when exporting fixed CHAR columns in a UTF8 session (since UTF8 is inherently a variable-length encoding). The default ExportWidth rule returns 2 bytes per character, and pads with spaces. VARCHAR columns use 2 bytes per character to calculate the maximum length but should return only the actual length with no added padding. You can add TRIM or CAST to VARCHAR in the SELECT statement on the Teradata side, or trim after exporting.

Answer (score 1):

We discuss this topic here in the Teradata JDBC Driver documentation:

https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_5.html#BGBJECGD

You can use CHARSET=UTF16 to avoid the extra trailing spaces with fixed-width CHAR columns.

Comment: Hi @Tom Nolan, Thank you for the document it worked for me I have a query is it efficient to use UTF16 as it is not compatible with ASCII do we get any issues.

Comment: UTF16 can be more efficient with fixed-width CHAR column values. UTF8 is typically more efficient for VARCHAR column values.